# React.js check if select option selected

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this code for select

```
<span>First Subject:</span>
<select name="firstPoint" onChange={e => handleInputs(e)}>
  <option value="0">-</option>
  <option value="4">A+</option>
  <option value="3.75">A</option>
  <option value="3.4">B+</option>
  <option value="3.1">B</option>
  <option value="2.75">C+</option>
  <option value="2.5">C</option>
  <option value="2.2">D+</option>
  <option value="2">D</option>
  <option value="1">F</option>
</select>
```

and this for `input`

```
<input
  type='number'
  name="firstHour"
  id='first-subject'
  min="0"
  max="3"
  placeholder='Credits hours'
  onChange={e => handleInputs(e)}
/>
```

screen for layout

[image]

I need If user enters a value in input like `First subject` must select option from `select input` for `First subject`

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the issues that you are facing in implementation?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have the idea to start implementing it. I don't know where to start

Comment: My understanding is, when user types a value in input(id: first-subject)  then  another value should be selected in 'select' input automatically. Let me know, if my understanding is correct.

Comment: when the user puts a value in the input, he must choose a value from the select next to the input and it is not automatically 
if user add value in `input(id: first-subject)` he must choose a value from `select` input for  `input(id: first-subject)`

Comment: Since both inputs values are entered by user, what is the challenge that you are facing? Are you not able to select a value in <select> element.